What is the measurement algorithm that the PyClifford's authors used?
I am studying how to perform measurements on pure stabilizer states of the Pyclifford package. The author used the convention to represent stabilizer states the same as in the paper: Improved Simulation of Stabilizer Circuits. However, the measurement, as well as the Projection from zero state to target states, and the expectation calculation use the same kind of manipulation which is different from the above paper.
I am gonna paste the code of measurement here for anyone to consider:
def stabilizer_measure(gs_stb, ps_stb, gs_obs, ps_obs, r):
'''Measure Pauli operators on a stabilizer state.

Parameters:
gs_stb: int (2*N, 2*N) - Pauli strings in original stabilizer tableau.
ps_stb: int (N) - phase indicators of (de)stabilizers.
gs_obs: int (L, 2*N) - strings of Pauli operators to be measured.
ps_obs: int (L) - phase indicators of Pauli operators to be measured.
r: int - log2 rank of density matrix (num of standby stablizers).

Returns:
gs_stb: int (2*N, 2*N) - Pauli strings in updated stabilizer tableau.
ps_stb: int (N) - phase indicators of (de)stabilizers.
r: int - updated log2 rank of density matrix.
out: int (L) - measurment outcomes (0 or 1 binaries).
log2prob: real - log2 probability of this outcome.'''
(L, Ng) = gs_obs.shape
N = Ng//2
assert 0<=r<=N
out = numpy.empty(L, dtype=numpy.int_)
ga = numpy.empty(2*N, dtype=numpy.int_) # workspace for stabilizer accumulation
pa = 0 # workspace for phase accumulation
log2prob = 0.
for k in range(L): # for each observable gs_obs[k]
    update = False
    extend = False
    p = 0 # pointer
    ga[:] = 0
    pa = 0
    for j in range(2*N):
        if acq(gs_stb[j], gs_obs[k]): # find gs_stb[j] anticommute with gs_obs[k]
            if update: # if gs_stb[j] is not the first anticommuting operator
                # update gs_stb[j] to commute with gs_obs[k]
                if j < N: # if gs_stb[j] is a stablizer, phase matters
                    ps_stb[j] = (ps_stb[j] + ps_stb[p] + ipow(gs_stb[j], gs_stb[p]))%4
                gs_stb[j] = (gs_stb[j] + gs_stb[p])%2
            else: # if gs_stb[j] is the first anticommuting operator
                if j < N + r: # if gs_stb[j] is not an active destabilizer
                    p = j # move pointer to j
                    update = True
                    if not r <= j < N: # if gs_stb[j] is a standby operator
                        extend = True
                else: # gs_stb[j] anticommute with destabilizer, meaning gs_obs[k] already a combination of active stabilizers
                    # collect corresponding stabilizer component to ga
                    pa = (pa + ps_stb[j-N] + ipow(ga, gs_stb[j-N]))%4
                    ga = (ga + gs_stb[j-N])%2
    if update:
        # now gs_stb[p] and gs_obs[k] anticommute
        q = (p+N)%(2*N) # get q as dual of p 
        gs_stb[q] = gs_stb[p] # move gs_stb[p] to gs_stb[q]
        gs_stb[p] = gs_obs[k] # add gs_obs[k] to gs_stb[p]
        if extend:
            r -= 1 # rank will reduce under extension
            # bring new stabilizer from p to r
            if p == r:
                pass
            elif q == r:
                gs_stb[numpy.array([p,q])] = gs_stb[numpy.array([q,p])] # swap p,q
            else:
                s = (r+N)%(2*N) # get s as dual of r
                gs_stb[numpy.array([p,r])] = gs_stb[numpy.array([r,p])] # swap p,r
                gs_stb[numpy.array([q,s])] = gs_stb[numpy.array([s,q])] # swap q,s
            p = r
        # as long as gs_obs[k] is not eigen, outcome will be half-to-half
        ps_stb[p] = 2 * numpy.random.randint(2)
        out[k] = ((ps_stb[p] - ps_obs[k])%4)//2 #0->0(+1 eigenvalue), 2->1(-1 eigenvalue)
        log2prob -= 1.
    else: # no update, gs_obs[k] is eigen, result is in pa
        assert((ga == gs_obs[k]).all())
        out[k] = ((pa - ps_obs[k])%4)//2
return gs_stb, ps_stb, r, out, log2prob

Does anyone know how to interpret this code? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!
